# Store signal values, output as vector for function input

Tags: matlab, simulink

Im trying to do some calculations in a Matlab (R2015b) Simulink function block. I use a signal that gives discrete values in 1-minute intervals.

What i want to do is store the signal values of 1 day (1440 values), convert them into a vector and input it in my Matlab function for calculation (getting time between first and last value > x). All while the simulation is running.

Unit delay, and Transport delay blocks wont work because i need all the stored values at once.
Any ideas on this are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "To Workspace" block to your simulink diagram. Setting the options as you wish will allow you to save all the outputs in a single vector. You can select the variable's name, and the default is "simout".

Then, after running the diagram, you have the variable you want in the workspace (as if you had typed it in the console). So next, you can call your function with the argument.

Comment: I have tried that, but i need the data from the current simulation run. And i can only access data from the workspace after the simulation is done, right?

Comment: Then, you are expecting to run a script or function in parallel to a Simulink diagram? AFAIK this is not possible. I'm sure there are methods to achieve what you need, but then I'm guessing you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.